# Cannot use tweepy on the free version of Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I was able to successfully authenticate my access keys and everything - however, I can't do pretty much any action without getting an error saying this is not in my access plan. Twitter says I am allowed 1500 tweets per month, but I can't use any of it?

I created a twitter bot using the many tutorials available online - however, whenever I try to use a method they are using, I get an error saying I don't have access to this endpoint and I may need a higher access plan. I am pasting my code and my error message while removing the keys and secrets:

```
import tweepy
key = ""
keySecret = " "
accessToken = " "
accessTokenSecret = " "
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key,keySecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.verify_credentials()

api.update_status("Test")
```

```
/Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/venv/bin/python /Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/imageProcessor.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/imageProcessor.py", line 11, in <module>
    api.update_status("Test")
  File "/Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 979, in update_status
    return self.request(
  File "/Users/kjj/PycharmProjects/personalTesting/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 271, in request
    raise Forbidden(resp)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: looks like Twitter is restricting the 1.1 API (which is what `tweepy.API` is) and favouring 2.0 (which is `tweepy.Client` - https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html#twitter-api-v2 )

Answer (score 2):

I might be late in answering but you can use tweepy.Client instead of tweepy.API
so your code when converted to tweepy.Client version will look like this.

```
import tweepy
key = ""
keySecret = " "
accessToken = " "
accessTokenSecret = " "
bearer_token=None
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token,key,keySecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
#below line is required but putting it here inplace of api.verify_credentials 
client.get_me() 
client.create_tweet(text="Test")
```

And this will work as you would expect it to work.